# Concurrent execution of streams and host functions

Tags: cuda

I have wrote a program which has two streams. Both streams operate on some data and write results back on the host memory.
Here is the generic structure of how i am doing this:

```
loop {
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream1);
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream2);

Kernel<<<...,Stream1>>>
Kernel<<<...,Stream2>>>

/* Write the results on the host memory */
AsyncCpy(....,DeviceToHost,Stream1);  
AsyncCpy(....,DeviceToHost,Stream2);  
}
```

I want to do some work on the CPU once i know that StreamX has finished copying the results back to the host memory. At the same time, i don't want to stop the loop from executing Async operations (memcpy or kernel execution).

If i insert my host functions, let say host_ftn1(..) and host_ftn2(..) like this

```
loop {
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream1);
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream2);

Kernel<<<...,Stream1>>>
Kernel<<<...,Stream2>>>

/* Write the results on the host memory to be processed by host_ftn1(..) */
AsyncCpy(....DeviceToHost,Stream1);
/* Write the results on the host memory to be processed by host_ftn2(..) */
AsyncCpy(....DeviceToHost,Stream2);  

if(Stream1 results are copied to host)
       host_ftn1(..);
if(Stream2 results are copied to host)
       host_ftn2(..);
}
```

It will stop the execution of loop until it finishes the execution of host functions i.e. host_ftn1 and host_ftn2, but I **don't want to stop the execution of GPU instructions** i.e. AsyncCpy(..) and Kernel<<<....,StreamX>>> while the CPU is busy executing the host functions i.e. host_ftn1(..) and host_ftn2(..)

Any solution/approach regarding this problem

Comment: Try callbacks or different streams with events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *huseyin tugrul buyukisik* suggested, the `stream callback` worked in this scenario. I have tested this for two streams.

The final design is as following:-

```
loop {
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream1);
AsyncCpy(....,HostToDevice,Stream2);

Kernel<<<...,Stream1>>>
Kernel<<<...,Stream2>>>

/* Write the results on the host memory to be processed by host_ftn1(..) */
AsyncCpy(....DeviceToHost,Stream1);
/* Write the results on the host memory to be processed by host_ftn2(..) */
AsyncCpy(....DeviceToHost,Stream2);  

callback1(..);    // Work to be done on the host once stream1 completes
callback2(..);    // Work to be done on the host once stream2 completes
}
```

See [Stream Callbacks](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-callbacks)